# PHP shell command

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell me how to move file(s) into a dir in PHP? I did the following and it doesn't work.

```
exec("temp/$file ../public/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[You should go about something like this :)](http://vdhri.net/2007/12/29/how-to-move-a-file-using-php/)**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the PHP functions [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) and then [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).